# Hi how do I get firebase to update my data in realtime?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The current set up I have pulls firebase data whenever the page is loaded this was great but now I need the data on my app to update in real-time how do I do this?

```
useEffect(() => {

    const user = Authentication.auth().currentUser;
    {
        user !== null &&
            Authentication.firestore().collection('Health_data')
                .doc(user.uid)
                .get()
                .then(doc => {
                    healthDataSet(doc.data())
                    setLoading(false)
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error("Error reading health", error);
                });
    }
    return () => {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
    }

}, []);

//calculates calorie requirments
useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && healthData !== null) {


        if (healthData.units === 'Kg') {
            BMIset(Math.round((healthData.weight / ((healthData.height / 100) * (healthData.height / 100))) * 10) / 10)


                if (healthData.gender === 'female') {
                    BMRset(Math.round(((655.1 + (9.563 * healthData.weight) + (1.850 * healthData.height) - (4.676 * healthData.age)) * 1.37) * 0.8))
                } else {
                    BMRset(Math.round(((88.2 + (13.362 * healthData.weight) + (4.799 * healthData.height) - (5.677 * healthData.age)) * 1.37) * 0.8))
                }

            }

            if (healthData.goal === 'Gain') {

                if (healthData.gender === 'female') {
                    BMRset(Math.round(((655.1 + (9.563 * healthData.weight) + (1.850 * healthData.height) - (4.676 * healthData.age)) * 1.37) * 1.2))
                } else {
                    BMRset(Math.round(((88.2 + (13.362 * healthData.weight) + (4.799 * healthData.height) - (5.677 * healthData.age)) * 1.37) * 1.2))
                }

            }

            if (healthData.goal === 'Recomp') {
                if (healthData.gender === 'female') {
                    BMRset(Math.round((655.1 + (9.563 * healthData.weight) + (1.850 * healthData.height) - (4.676 * healthData.age)) * 1.37))
                } else {
                    BMRset(Math.round((88.2 + (13.362 * healthData.weight) + (4.799 * healthData.height) - (5.677 * healthData.age)) * 1.37))
                }
```

so here's my code after the data is pulled the data is used for calculations I want it so when the data is updated like this.

```
  const updateWeight = () => {
        if (Weight !== null) {
            database.collection('Health_data').doc(localStorage.getItem('user')).update({
                weight: Weight
            }).catch((error) => {
                alert(error.message)
                console.log('failed to write', error);
            });
        } else {
            alert('A weight must be in put')
        }
    }
```

The calculations get new information and the page is updated in real time is this possible?

Comment: I suggest starting with the documentation to understand how it works: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: thats the site ive been looking at thanks mate but no luck with the implementation

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's suggested that you post the code that isn't working the way you expect, and explain what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> You can listen to a document with the **onSnapshot()** method. An initial
>   call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot
>   immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then,
>   each time the contents change, another call updates the document
>   snapshot.

For more details head to this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web_1

Comment: Thank I'll try that, I think thats what I tried before but I couldn't get it working

Comment: Please let me know where you are facing problem if it doesn't work?

Comment: It doesnt seem to work at I get this error https://imgur.com/1BBpJD8

Comment: https://imgur.com/undefined have also tried phrasing it as firebase site suggests not in react form but I get this error I'm sure its me doing something wrong though hahaha

Comment: You can't use both **.get()** and **.onSnapshot()** at the same time..I would request to go through the documentation once for clearly to get the idea of your requirements.

Comment: I removed the .get before you posted same error but ill read through one more time thanks

Comment: I've read through I understand the theory but not the implementation into react? doesn't seem to be working could you please help me

Comment: Ok so it turns out the whole time the error was because catch isn't a function of a snapshot...